# OSError during "pip install jupyterlab" about a file not being found. How can I fix this?

Tags: installation, pip, jupyter, jupyter-lab, oserror

this is my pip version:

> pip 21.1.1 from c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

when I run this command:
`pip install jupyterlab`
It fails eventually trying to install packages with this error:

> WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\python39\Scripts\jupyter-kernel.exe' -> 'c:\python39\Scripts\jupyter-kernel.exe.deleteme'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try running cmd as admin

Answer (score 0):

try manually removing 'c:\python39\Scripts\jupyter-kernel.exe'

Comment: Please use comments instead of answers for this type of suggestions.